# Changing the maxTransactionSize using Corda OS v3.x with network bootstrapper

Tags: corda

Can we change maxTransactionSize in Corda OS v3.x with network bootstrapper?

Also the default value of maxTransactionSize is 525MB? as per the below code?
https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/node-api/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/nodeapi/internal/network/NetworkBootstrapper.kt#L420

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Corda 3, there is no way to change the network parameters of a bootstrapped network, except for adding additional whitelisted contract JARs.

In Corda 4, a mechanism will be introduced to allow the network parameters of a bootstrapped network to be modified.

The default max transaction size is actually given [here](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release-V3/node-api/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/nodeapi/internal/network/NetworkBootstrapper.kt#L205) and is 2048MB.