# Corda, TestNet: Is it allowed to modify the X.500 name of a pre-configured Corda node downloaded from https://testnet.corda.network

Tags: corda

We have downloaded 4 pre-configured Corda nodes from https://testnet.corda.network.
These nodes have X.500 distinguished names containing subparts - Organization, Location and Country.

Question 1: Can we replace the values in the above subparts of the X.500 distinguished name with our definitions?

Question 2: Can we add "organizationUnit" in the above X.500 name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Testnet was built for the community to experience the Corda network. 
It is a pathway to `the Corda Network (TCN)` run by the Corda Foundation, an independent council which runs the TCN.

I will log your requests with the testnet team as a function enhancement request, but they will probably need more information from you & your team to make any further changes to the testnet.

You can reach me at http://slack.corda.net. We can resume the conversation there.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, every node specifies its own X500 name. This is done in the node.conf using the `myLegalName` field: https://docs.corda.net/corda-configuration-file.html#configuration-file-fields This field is used during initial registration on the node's first startup to register with the network's identity service https://docs.corda.r3.com/node-commandline.html#sub-commands

The X500 name for a name of a node is extremely important as it represents the identity that a node uses when signing transaction. Because of this the X500 identity rules vary by network.

**Testnet**

The [onboarding tool](https://marketplace.r3.com/network/testnet/install-node) pre-generates an X500 for you based on your marketplace account. Your account is automatically built into a generated node.conf which`install.sh` downloads for your node.

In Testnet there are no restrictions on identity and all registration requests are automatically approved. Therefore anyone can specify any identity they would like which is why Testnet must never be used for real financial transactions.

**UAT**

X500 names must followed a specific set of rules to be approved. Guidelines on how to select an X500 are here: https://corda.network/participation/distinguishedname.html

Examples of real world identity selection is here: https://corda.network/participation/legalentity.html

In UAT registration requests are all manually approved by the Corda Network Foundation. Follows the steps outlined here to onboard your node: https://uat.network.r3.com/pages/joining/joining.html

**The Corda Network (tCN)**

The production Corda Network follows the same guidelines for X500 names.

The onboarding process for nodes is also the same with different urls: https://corda.network/participation/index.html